# Microlocal approach to definition of product of distributions

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis, schwartz-distributions, micro-local-analysis

My question may be simple to an expert, but I'm not:

Let's consider $u \in C^{s}(\mathbb{R}^d)$ be a Hölder function sor some $s\in [0,1/2)$ which we may take very close to $0$.

Of course, $u^2 \in C^{s}(\mathbb{R}^d)$ so that $(u^2)' \in B^{s-1}_{\infty,\infty}$, is a well-defined distribution, with some explicit negative regularity.

So it means that in this case one can define $u'u = (u^2)'$ as a distribution. But if one wants to define the product $u'u$ by using some general rule, like defining $vu$ for $u\in C^s$, $v\in C^{s-1}$, when $s>1/2$. But for $s<1/2$, this is not possible this way.

I know that there are critera like if $\{(x,\xi) \vert (x,\xi) \in WF(u), (x,-\xi)\in WF(v)\}=\varnothing$ then $uv$ is well-defined as a distribution. So my question is the following:

> Is there a way to apply these microlocal tools to define $u'u$ when $u\in C^s$, $s \ll 1$?

Comment: I think the theory of paraproducts (e.g., the Coifman-Meyer multiplier theorem) is more relevant here than classical microlocal analysis; one can hope to define various paraproducts at regularities below what one might naively expect if there are suitable cancellations in the associated bilinear symbol.  See also the div-curl lemma for another instance of this phenomenon.

Comment: @TerryTao thank you for your comment. In fact I had in mind these kind of div-curl lemma somewhat magial cancellations, but I'm not an expert on this. What would you suggest as a good reference to see these "cancellations in the associated bilinear symbol" in action?

Comment: I don't have it at hand, but perhaps Taylor's "Tools for PDE" covers some of this material.

Comment: Thank you, I'll take a look at Taylor's books!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Too long for a comment. For $u$ in $C^s$, $s\in (0,1)$, you can indeed define $u^2$ and then the distribution-derivative of $u^2$, which belongs to $B^{s-1}_{\infty,\infty}$. Now that does not define the product $uu'$, unless you decide to define that product as $\frac12(u^2)'$. Assuming for instance that $u$ is also compactly supported, you can mollify everything and consider $u_\epsilon=u\ast \rho_\epsilon$
and  you will have trouble at proving that
$$
u u'_\epsilon
$$
has a (weak) limit in the distribution sense when $s<1/2$.

About your question, I believe that the answer is negative.
One reason is that you may consider only real-valued functions defined on the real line: in that case the wave-front-set is trivially deduced from the singular support and is
$$
\text{singsupp} u\times \mathbb R^*.
$$
So microlocal analysis is of no help in that situation, whereas your problem of defining $uu'$ in that simple situation remains the same.

Comment: Thank you @Bazin!